# What's the most Pythonic way to translate (d1, d2)[] to {d3: d2[]} where g(d1) generates d3[]

Tags: python

I've got a data structure that looks like this:

```
data = [
    (16, 'a'),
    (12, 'b'),
    (21, 'c'),
    (30, 'b'),
    (17, 'd'),
    ...
]
```

The numbers are large (more than 32 bits), non-sequential, non-unique, and not in order. The strings may repeat.

I've got a generator:

```
def factors(n):
  for d in range(2, 5):
    if n % d == 0:
      yield n
```

It can generate zero or more values. The results are not unique for each input. What I need is this:

```
result = {
    2: ['a', 'b', 'b'],  # 16, 12, 30
    3: ['b', 'c', 'b'],  # 12, 21, 30
    4: ['a', 'b']        # 16, 12
]
```

I'd like to stay as close to standard Python modules as possible (no numpy). The best I've got is this:

```
result = {}
for a, b in data:
  for c in factors(a):
    result.setdefault(c).append(b)
```

But this feels weird, and I'm used to Python handling things like this more elegantly.

Comment: Why did the factors stop at `4`?

Comment: … no, that seems pretty much how you’d do it! (You can use a `defaultdict(list)` instead of a `setdefault`, though, assuming your real code is `setdefault(c, [])`.)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye 4 factors should be enough for anyone (ha ha).  Actually it was to demonstrate that the list could be duplicated. If you had 12 and 24 in the list, both would generate [2, 3, 4].  That was in as an example during a draft, guess it was dropped.

Comment: using `setdefault` or `defaultdict` is how you would do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating first on `data` and then on `factors`. I would do the other way around, because that way the `result` builds much more naturally:

```
result = {}
for d in range(2, 5):
    result[d] = [b for (a,b) in data if a % d == 0]
```

Or if you feel brave enough to do a double comprehension:

```
result = dict((d, [b for (a,b) in data if a % d == 0]) for d in range(2, 5))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the entire set of factors ahead of time. This was a simplified example.